# When objects are charged via friction, what are the objects' initial charges?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, friction

When objects are charged via induction, one object is initially charged and the other is initially neutral.

When objects are charged (or neutralized, in this case) via conduction, one object is initially charged, and the other is either neutral or oppositely charged.

What about friction? The way I understand it, both objects (insulators in many cases) are neutrally charged. Then, due to the frictional heat, one acquires a negative charge and the other a positive charge.

Am I understanding this correctly? Feel free to correct, or elaborate on, my two initial axioms as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "charged with friction"?  Are your referring to the "tribolectric effect"?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the triboelectric effect.

Comment: [Triboelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect)